# executing a function for 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to do a loading bar in p5.js where I have a bar on the top like YouTube loading bar.

like so

```
var x = 0;
function setup() { 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
    x = width;
} 
function draw() { 
  background(220);
    stroke(255,0,0);
    strokeWeight(10);
    line(0,0,x,0);
}
```

I want to use the `map()` function where I can reduce the width of the line.

```
map(x, width , 0 , second(),second()+5);
```

[Working Example](http://alpha.editor.p5js.org/zusamarehan/sketches/H1nZzfdMf)

**NOTE**:Using p5.js library

Comment: add a functional example using so snippet or fiddler.

Comment: @VipinKumar check out the link in the Question

Comment: Please link between crossposts, that way people don't waste their time repeating advice you've already received: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/25653/executing-a-function-for-only-5-seconds

Comment: @KevinWorkman I have no intention to waste anyone's time. I asked the question in processing forum before I asked here. From my point of view there is nothing wrong in asking and learning from different people as each and every individual has their own approach. If I have offended anyone I am sorry for that.

Comment: @Rehan My only point is that now that you have an answer here, anybody who answers you on the Processing forum **without seeing this answer** will be wasting their time. It's okay to post in multiple places, but **please link between those posts** so we can see what has already been said elsewhere.

Comment: umm,I agree I should have linked. Thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `x` should not be made equal to the `width`. It should start at `0` and then only update based on the time.

Secondly `second()` returns the actual seconds of the current time, so it is not good for this case. Better to use the `millis()` which returns the milliseconds since the project started.

Finally you are using the `map` parameters wrong (*or at least i do not understand what you are trying to do with the order you are passing them*)

```
x = map(millis(), 0, 5000, 0 , width);
```

The above will map the milliseconds range `0 - 5000` (*0 to 5 seconds*) to the `0 - width` of the canvas.

---

To be able to initialize the bar at any time then use a variable for the start/end values of the value range.

```
var x,
    startAt;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  startAt = millis();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(10);

  x = map(millis(), startAt, startAt + 5000, 0, width);
  line(0, 0, x, 0);
}

function mouseClicked() {
  startAt = millis();
}
```

In this example whenever you click, the bar will be restarted.

Working example at http://alpha.editor.p5js.org/gpetrioli/sketches/SyibBz_ff

Comment: this will work only for the starting 5 seconds of the project,but I want to show the loading bar at any given point inside of the running project..

Comment: @Rehan then instead of 0 and 5000 as the range use a variable which is initialized to `millis()` the moment you want to start and that + 5000 for its end.

Comment: @Rehan I have updated the example to support this. It restarts when you click the mouse (*for the example*)

Comment: Thats so nice of you. Thank you for you help. Appreciate it.